# Swift 2.0 - "Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSURL' to return type 'String' "

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am attempting to convert an old swift app to 2.0 and can't seem to get past this bit of code in this function:

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);

    let path = paths[0] ;

    let fullPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)

    return fullPath

}
```

On the "let fullPath" line I get the error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSURL' to return type 'String'"

Here is the full .swift file:

```
import UIKit

class CardViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var SecondCaptureButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var OpenButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var MainCaptureButton: UIButton!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

 /* func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } */


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    OpenButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    OpenButton.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    MainCaptureButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    MainCaptureButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    MainCaptureButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    MainCaptureButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let possibleOldImagePath = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("path") as! String?

    if let oldImagePath = possibleOldImagePath {

        let oldFullPath = self.documentsPathForFileName(oldImagePath)

        let oldImageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: oldFullPath)

        // here is your saved image:

        if let oldImage = UIImage(data: oldImageData!) {

            imageView.image = oldImage
            print("Old Photo Retrieved")

            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)

        }

    }
}

func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);

    let path = paths[0] ;

    let fullPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)

    return fullPath

}

@IBAction func TakePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(MainCaptureButton)
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)
    let relativePath = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()).jpg"
    let path = self.documentsPathForFileName(relativePath)

    imageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(relativePath, forKey: "path")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    print("New Photo Saved")


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Comment: NSURL( ...) returns an NSURL object, NOT String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is defined to return a String:

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String { ...
```

but you are trying to return an `NSURL`. You could either change your method signature to return an `NSURL`:

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> NSURL { ...
```

or you could return a string representation of the URL:

```
return fullPath.absoluteString
```

Comment: `absoluteString` is not appropriate in this case because it returns also the leading scheme `file://`

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear.

`fullPath` is an `NSURL` instance, the return value is `String`

Either change the return value

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> NSURL {
    let fullPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
    return fullPath
}
```

Or return a string

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {
    let fullPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
    return fullPath
}
```

I omitted the local variable `path` because it's not used in the snippet.